# Which gate based quantum computer is the best?

Tags: qiskit

I am interested in Drug Discovery and Materials Simulation.

I was told that the IBM 433 qubit quantum computer can only do a circuit of 11 qubits x 11 gates. And Honeywell's quantum computer can only do 12 qubits x 12 gates.

I have two questions...
Is that true?
Is it better to go for a 30-40 qubit quantum simulator instead?

Comment: There are some magnetic system simulations which show better performance in a quantum computer against the next best classical methods. [Example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03446)

Comment: What is being referred to by the 11 qubits x 11 gates and 12 qubits x 12 gates is a benchmarking protocol called [Quantum Volume](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12926). The reasoning is that a device can pass a quantum volume of $2^n$ can execute quantum circuits of gate depth $n$ and qubit number $n$ reasonably well (but not perfectly). Short answer: it depends on the device error rates, connectivity, and number of qubits. I recently worked on a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03816) where we executed quantum volume circuits on a large number of current quantum computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2023, except for [random circuit sampling experiments](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11333), there have been no experiments of any kind on a quantum computer where the computation couldn't have been done faster and cheaper and more accurately by using a simulator.

Go into any paper, ignore what it says in the title or the abstract, and just count how many gates and qubits appear in the circuit diagrams and look at how noisy the results are. Simulators are still hands-down better. And I don't even mean big simulators, just... simulators. Stuff you can run in milliseconds on a laptop. That won't remain true forever, hardware is improving and the fault tolerant era is coming, but it's true for now.

Comment: Thankyou so much Craig. I appreciate your candid, objective and to the point response to my question. Further, would you happen to know which Simulators are the best for 36-40 Qubit Range? is there any free open source option? or do I have to buy an appliance? or should I go with a cloud subscription? Just in case you happen to know. I'm not a Quantum Physicist or a Software guy. So please pardon my ignorance when I ask naive questions.

Comment: @ElijahConnor You shouldn't be buying a simulator if you're new to the field. There are perfectly good open source ones that will meet your needs. Only buy one after you understand the circuit you want to run at smaller sizes and decide that you actually need a bigger simulation.